# Replacing the avatar on the animator component does not seem to be changing the avatar?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I want to replace this little dude with a pink hat with a skeleton.

This is the skeleton:

[image]

As you can see the avatar is Skelton@SkinAvatar

Now the gameobject below had a man with pink hat as the avatar (it has a ton of components on it, all I want to change is the avatar). I tried to replace it with the skeleton avatar, but it did not change.

[image]

As you can see above I changed it to also use the Skeleton@SkinAvatar but that change is not reflected in what is showing on the screen. It is still showing the old pink hat man avatar. Any ideas why?

any help appreciated. thanks

edit: here is a better screenshot showing all the components
[image]

Comment: the avatar is not the mesh.. which is what you see

Comment: ok thanks, how could i also update the mesh? there is no mesh component at all. i cant post a screenshot of all the components on the object if that helps

Comment: ok i just updated my op showing all the components

Comment: show the heirachy, i imagine the mesh is underneath that top object

Comment: ok thanks a lot got it